# Show that ... Has No Real Roots

Tags: functions, roots

When $f(x) = 3x-4$ and $g(x) = \frac{5}{3-x}$,

Question 1: Find the value of x for which fg(x) = 5

Question 2: Show that the equation $f^{-1}(x) = g^{-1}(x)$ has no real roots.

I understand that in question 1 it simply is asking to plug 5 into the x and then solve for fg(x) =

5/(3-5) = -2.5

3(-2.5) - 4 = -11.5 (this is all right so far?)

I don't understand question 2, or how exactly I should answer it. How do I work out that there are no real roots? This is how the question is asked. Obviously the functions have to first be in the inverse forms.

I'm not an Einstein when it comes to working out roots - so if possible - please explain each step taken so that I may understand this type of question in the future.

Many thanks,
Student909.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate  what have you attempted and where are you stuck.

Comment: Question 2 is quite easy because you can explicit the inverse in both cases: you have $x=\frac{y+4}{3}$ and $x=\frac{3y-5}{y}$ hence your resolvent equation has discriminant negative.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=3x-4$$
$$x=\frac{f(x)+4}3$$
$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+4}3$$
$$g(x)=\frac{5}{3-x}$$
$$x=3-\frac{5}{g(x)}$$
$$g^{-1}(x)=3-\frac{5}{x}$$
$$f^{-1}(x)-g^{-1}(x)=\frac x3+\frac43-3+\frac 5x=\frac{x^2-5x+15}{3x}$$
The discriminant of $x^2-5x+15$ is negative. So, $x^2-5x+15\ne0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Thus, $$f^{-1}(x)-g^{-1}(x)\ne0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

As a result, $$f^{-1}(x)=g^{-1}(x)$$ has no real roots.